# Universal Injectivity of Morphisms of Finite Type $k$-Scheme can be checked on the level of sets at closed points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is Vakil 10.1 P c). This is self-study, not homework.

The problem asks one to show that a map $\pi: X \to Y$ of finite type $k$-schemes over an algebraically closed field $k = \overline{k}$ is universally injective if and only if it is injective on closed points.

My proof is as follows: $\pi$ is universally injective if and only if its diagonal map $\delta_{\pi} : X \to X \times_Y X$ is surjective. By exercise 7.4 E, this happens if and only if $\delta_{\pi}$ is surjective on closed points (I did not need the reduced assumption in my proof of 7.4 E, only the finite-type...was reduced needed?), and I believe this happens if and only if $\pi$ is injective on closed points.

My issue is with proving the last equivalence, and with the fact that I never used that $k = \overline{k}$. Is this needed? Also, did I need the reduced assumption for 7.4 E? If so, then I cannot appeal to that result immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $k$ is algebraically closed, the closed points of $X$ (resp. $X \times_Y X$) are the elements of $X(k)$ (resp. $X(k)\times_{Y(k)}X(k)$), and thus $\delta_{\pi}(k)$ is surjective iff $X(k) \rightarrow Y(k)$ is injective (that is set-theoretical), ie iff $\pi$ is injective on closed points.

Note that if $k$ isn't algebraically closed, it is easy for $\pi$ to be injective on closed points without $\delta_{\pi}$ to be surjective on closed points. Take for instance, if $k$ isn't its own separable closure, $Y=\mathrm{Spec}\,k$ and $X=\mathrm{Spec}\,K$ where $K$ is a Galois extension of $k$.